# jquery mobile 1.4.0 ajax error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

So I've switch to jquery mobile 1.4.0-rc.1 and I'm having an error after changing.
And I'm having an error to this code and other similar code.

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
$.mobile.changePage( "index.html", { changeHash: true });
```

I'm getting the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loading' of undefined**

And I read that this is deprecated for the new version. I can't find the replacements for this.

Can anyone help me to resolve this or can someone give the fix to this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "index.html");` as `$.mobile.changePage` is deprecated.

Comment: judging by your error, you seem to invoke $.mobile before it's there. You should provide some more code, so we can see when you call the loader and why `$.mobile` is not defined yet

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even with the release of the stable 1.4 version, the documentation is still at a very early stage, and it's quite hard to find replacements for deprecated functions.

According to the pagecontainer api (but not directly stated), it seems that the selector ':mobile-pagecontainer' can be used to access the pagecontainer object, and also execute a page change:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#new_page');
```

Notice of this can be found in the first part of the hide event example: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-hide

For what concerns the **loader** widget, if the related api is up to date (http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/) it hasn't been deprecated with this new 1.4 version, so problems with it should be sought elsewhere.